# Unable to upload image using the Wordpress admin 'Insert Media' option

Tags: wordpress

I am running WordPress 4.3 and in the admin I am no longer able to upload images using the standard upload image tool. I am taking over a project from another developer so don't know exactly what he/she has changed.

The 'Insert Media' box pops up, however when I click the 'Select Files' nothing happens. I would expect it to browse to a folder on my PC to allow an image upload. There are no console log errors and I cannot see the best way to debug this - can anyone suggest my next step to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no errors, it may be due dequeued scripts. Try to add this to your function.php

```
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'ca_restore_wp_media', 9000);//hope that 9000 priority will be executed last, if not try to increase

    function ca_restore_wp_media($hook){ 
        if( is_admin() )//be sure that it's admin
        {
            //JQuery
            wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
            //Image picker
            wp_enqueue_media();
        }
    }
```